# Error in tbl_summary(.) : could not find function "tbl_summary"

Tags: r, gtsummary

I'm learning R as a med student and have been asked to create a summary table from data that is coming back for a research project.

I honestly have not idea what the best way to do this is given it seems to be quite a lot of data. I have opted for the gtsummary package but keep getting the following message: Error in tbl_summary(.) : could not find function "tbl_summary"

Here is my code:

```
data %>% 
  select(age_years, gender, weight, height, pregnant, breastfeeding, income, work_intensity, religion, marital, education) %>%  # keep only the columns of interest
  tbl_summary()                                                  # default
```

The package is loaded but please let me know what is up, I feel a bit out of my depth. Alternatively, if anyone has a more intuitive way to make a customisable summary table then please let me know. I have to customise the data after this for age ranges and include a whole lot more variables but for now I would just like the initial code to work haha!

Comment: Welcome to SO! _"/../ The package is loaded /../"_ most likely it is not, at least not in your current R session. You can check with `sessionInfo()` , packages listed under "other attached packages" . You can also include `sessionInfo()`  output to your question and show the code that loads `gtsummary`?  . Was loading OK, it did not trigger any errors?   Are you sure you have executed the line or a RMarkodown/Quarto/Jupyter code cell with `library(gtsummary)` in your current(!) R session?

Comment: ahh thank you so much - i double checked and I get this message when i unticked and ticked the gtsummary package: > library(gtsummary)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘gtsummary’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 namespace ‘cli’ 3.4.1 is already loaded, but >= 3.6.1 is required